# "access to site analytics", is that a new thing?

Tags: support, site-analytics

I just got *access to site analytics* achievement,  which the linked help says is at 5000 points. Is this a new feature that's being applied en masse to everyone who qualifies, or what?

Comment: I assume so.  I noticed the same achievement but haven't done anything with it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a new privilege that's rolling out now.  See [the help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) for the details on how to use it, and [this Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260849/162102) for the background.

It's granted at 25k on graduated sites and 5k on beta sites.  Even if you haven't gotten a notification yet, if you have the rep you probably have access -- *privilege notifications* seem to be generated only on reputation changes.

Comment: If WB gets graduated, do we keep the privileges we have, or do we have to reacquire them, such as going from 5k to 25k rep for the analytics?

Comment: @Frostfyre the latter; when a site graduates it moves to the new privilege levels and some users lose privileges.  This is why, sometimes, a site that is otherwise doing well is held back -- there need to be enough users at the higher privilege levels to not break the community.  (No, I don't know what "enough" is.)